# Capture HTML textbox value in python without CGI

Tags: python, html

I need to get the user input in a textbox and process it using my python script when user presses Submit button. Unfortunately I am using an external server that does not support CGI. Is there any other way I can do this? This is my sample HTML.

```
<body>
    <form name="form1" method="post" action="script1.py">
        <div id="heading"><big><big><big>My analysis</big></big></big></div>
        <textarea cols="50" rows="1" name="Query_text" id="Query_text"></textarea>
        <div id="Button"><input name="Submit" value="Submit" type="submit"></div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the form processing with Javascript but hopefully you don't want to save this input beyond the next page the person accesses.  Another old school option is emailing yourself the contents of Query_text.  But honestly this is a lot more work than you want to do and not worth the effort (for most people).  What you need is a new web host.